# How we can Add marker on each points in LineChart using charts swift

Tags: ios, swift, charts, linechart

When I'm trying to show marker on each entry in LineChart using Charts framework.

```
let marker = BalloonMarker(color: .kPhysicsColor,
                           font: UIFont.medium(size: 11),
                           textColor: .white,
                           insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 10, right: 3))
marker.chartView = chartView
marker.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 28, height: 20)
chartView.marker = marker

let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
chartView.data = lineChartData
```

How we can show marker on each entry point in LineChart using charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `Charts`, you can use the `highlightValues` method on the `chartView` object to to set the values you want to be drawn without user interaction.

For this solution to work, remember to have `drawMarkers` set to `true`.

Comment: I want to show marker only when I touch over the line or circle in LineChart, How I can do this ?